# ASP.NET Core updated - continous deployment to Azure broken

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I've updated my old ASP.NET Core MVC project to 1.1.1 and pushed the changes. I have CD set up in Azure for Web App. And this build failed with the following:

> > Local gulp not found in D:\home\site\repository
> >
> > Try running: npm install gulp

so, what's changed and why it doesn't run `npm install` anymore? how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To restore NuGet packages & run npm command, you could create Custom Continuous Deployment Script(Kudu) for your application.

To download or get default kudu script into your local repository you need to install Azure CLI

```
npm install azure-cli -g
```

It will create two files in you directory .deployment & deploy.cmd. In deploy.cmd file, following code will help us restore NuGet packages.

```
echo =======  Restore NuGet packages: Starting at %TIME% ======= 

IF /I "Solution.Name.sln" NEQ "" (

  call :ExecuteCmd nuget restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Solution.Name.sln"

  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

)

echo =======  Restore NuGet packages: Finished at %TIME% =======
```

To run npm install command, you need to add following code to deploy.cmd.

```
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi
```

For more information, links below are for your reference.

[Custom Continuous Deployment Script(Kudu) for Asp.net app on Azure](https://github.com/premchandrasingh/kuduscript/tree/master/asp.net)

[Run NPM, Bower, Composer, Gulp & Grunt In Azure App Services During Deployment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/08/12/run-npm-bower-composer-gulp-grunt-in-azure-app-services-during-deployment/)

Comment: This was used to be a 1-click task. Why has it became such a hassle? I better go with Continuous Integration pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected the app from Deployment Options and used Continuous Delivery instead. Used Deploy .NET Core (PREVIEW) template (or whatever it's called), added one extra Task to run `npm install` and that's it. Works like a charm.